# Using a capturing group of the match pattern of a regsub in the substitution itself?

Tags: regex, tcl

In the code below, `$html` is a string of HTML. The code captures the full match and the capturing group for each match in a list. Then, if the list is not empty, it iterates through the list to replace the `span` tags with `em` tags along with the original text that was between them.

For example if the HTML is:
`This is <span class='add'>span 1</span> and this is <span class='add'>span 2</span>.` then `$a` would be a list of length 4: `{<span class='add'>span 1</span>} {span 1} {<span class='add'>span 2</span>} {span 2}`.

The sample code generates:
`This is <em>span 1</em> and this is <em>span 2</em>.` as expected; but it seems that this must be an inefficient way to do this and, somehow, the capturing group should be usable directly within the `regsub` expression.

Is this true and how is it done?

Something like:

`set html [regsub "<span class='add'>(.+?)</span>" $html "<em>.../em>"]`

where the `...` is something that points to the captured group.

Thank you.

```
set a [regexp -all -inline -- {<span class='add'>(.+?)</span>} $html]
if { [llength $a] > 0 } {
  foreach {x y} $a {
    set html [regsub "<span class='add'>${y}</span>" $html "<em>${y}</em>"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a backreference in the replacement:

```
regsub -all {<span class='add'>(.+?)</span>} $html {<em>\1</em>}
```

EDIT: To trim leading and trailing spaces from the captured string, you can simply leave them out by matching leading and trailing spaces outside the parentheses:

```
regsub -all {<span class='add'>\s*(.+?)\s*</span>} $html {<em>\1</em>}
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask a follow-up please?  What is I needed to perform a `[string trim ...]` on the captured group before substitution such as `{<em>[string trim \1]</em>}`? I know that doesn't work but is it possible? Thanks again.

Comment: This processes without error but does not trim the string in the captured group `"[string trim {\1}]"` and returns the same returns the same results as simply `{\1}`.

Comment: Replacement strings in tcl can't contain expressions. Instead, leave out leading and trailing spaces from the captured group, as shown above.

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems quite simple and obvious now but it never occurred to me. I appreciate the help.